# Element in distinct prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal O$ its ring of algebraic integers.

Let $\mathfrak p_1,\ldots , \mathfrak p_n$  prime ideals of $\mathcal O$ with $\mathfrak p_i\neq\mathfrak p_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Let $ \pi_j\in \mathfrak p_j\setminus \displaystyle\prod_{l\neq j} \mathfrak p_l$

My question is: $\pi_j\notin \mathfrak p_i\setminus \displaystyle\prod_{l\neq i} \mathfrak p_l$ if $i\neq j$?

Thank you all.

Comment: If $\pi_j\in \mathfrak p_j\setminus \displaystyle\prod_{l\neq j} \mathfrak p_l$, then $\pi_j$ is in none of the $\mathfrak p_k$ except for $\mathfrak p_j$, so certainly it is not in $\mathfrak p_i$ if $i\ne j$, so it is not in  $\mathfrak p_i\setminus \displaystyle\prod_{l\neq i} \mathfrak p_l$. Is this the question you intended to ask?

Comment: roger; I'm confused, why $\pi_j$ is in none of the $\mathfrak p_k$ ($k\neq j$)?

Comment: @user126033: You are right to be confused, because rogerl's comment is completely false: any three prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ generate prime ideals which give a counterexample to his claim.